# The relation between two variables and one another variable

Tags: phrase-request

How can I point out the relation between 3 variables? I want to point out the relation between (A, B) and (C). e.g., in the relation bellow, C depends both A and B.

```
C = 2 * A + B
```

Is the phrase bellow correct?

```
the relation between A as well as B and C
```

Comment: Go for the simplest phrasing possible: **the relation between A, B and C**.

Comment: To avoid any possible confusion we use *brackets* in actual equations. For a text-based format, use something like *the relation of C to **both** A and B*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The phrase is correct, but jarring and overcomplicated**

---

The phrase you're asking for, does join the three terms together in a grammatically correct way. However, it is a real mouthful to speak and most people would tend to a simpler alternative.

What you asked in the opening question:

> I want to point out **the relation**[ship] **between (A, B) and (C)**

Works well to describe the situation.

That said, these phrases will likely suggest that there is a relationship between all three (A, B and C). Which is technically correct, but perhaps not the focus you want to give.

---

Instead, to focus on the specific relationship between (A,B) and (C) - I'd suggest a phrase along the lines of:

> C's dependency on A and B

or

> The dependency of C on A and B.

Which is a specific type of relationship - and conveys the specific situation more clearly.

Comment: Or, most simply, "C is a function of A and B."